# pass an array of data through a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, apex

I'm working with an apex graph:[image: The graph in question]

It needs 2 arrays, 1 being the data of the current year and the other from last year, showing the difference between 2 years (or months).
I have succeeded into making it work with php, but I need to make it more dynamic so I decided to make it using jquery.

```
var sum = "";
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
      sum += v["sum"] + ', ';
    })
```

This piece of code stores all this data:

> 605.00, 4575.00, 4405.00, 3865.00, 3430.00, 2670.00, 1975.00, 650.00, 1945.00, 2800.00, 1960.00, 1905.00, 1600.00, 2070.00, 750.00, 2415.00, 1330.00, 1470.00, 1295.00, 2190.00, 1525.00, 300.00, 2255.00, 1270.00, 1230.00, 1330.00, 1405.00, 1140.00, 1200.00, 1725.00, 1775.00,

Now I need to grab the variable `sum` and insert it into the graph. This is my attempt:

```
name:"Current Month",type:"line",data:[sum]}]
```

The `sum` variable seen in that line of code is supposed to send that string of numbers into the graph but for some reason it's not working. Am I supposed to echo it somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is `sum` a string? Just make it an actual array and push `v["sum"]` into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sum` variable is a string, so you're actually passing in the data like an array with one string element, like this:

```
['605.00, 4575.00, 4405.00, 3865.00, 3430.00, 2670.00, 1975.00, 650.00, 1945.00, 2800.00, 1960.00, 1905.00, 1600.00, 2070.00, 750.00, 2415.00, 1330.00, 1470.00, 1295.00, 2190.00, 1525.00, 300.00, 2255.00, 1270.00, 1230.00, 1330.00, 1405.00, 1140.00, 1200.00, 1725.00, 1775.00,']
```

You probably need to ensure it's just a normal array of data:

```
var sum = [];
$.each(data, function(k, v){
    sum.push(v['sum']);
});
```

Then reference that variable directly as your data:

```
name:"Current Month", type:"line", data:sum
```